# c# query for combobox selected text

Tags: c#

I am creating a windows form application that generates timetable automatically. I am having a problem to write a query when a user select semester number from the dropdown(from 1-8) then what should I write in query? My Code is below.

```
private void button_generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand com;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAJOR-DYNASTI;Initial Catalog=ESS;Integrated Security=True");
   con.Open();
    string a = comboBox_semester.SelectedText;
    string str = "SELECT  CourseName, TeacherName, RoomName FROM Course_teacher, RoomInfo where Semester= ORDER BY NEWID(); ";
    com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {

        Random random = new Random();
        var labels = new Label[] { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8,label9,label10,label11,label12,label13,label14,label15,label16,
                                   label17,label18,label19,label20,label21,label22,label23,label24,label25,label26,label27,label28,label29,label30,label31,
                                    label32,label33,label34,label35,label36,label37,label38,label39,label40,label41,label42,label43,label44,label45,label46,label47,label48,
                                    label49,label50};
        label1.Text = ""; label2.Text = ""; label3.Text = ""; label4.Text = ""; label5.Text = ""; label6.Text = "";
        label7.Text = "";label8.Text = "";label9.Text = "";label10.Text = "";label11.Text = "";label12.Text = "";label13.Text = "";label14.Text = "";label15.Text = "";label16.Text = "";
                                   label17.Text = "";label18.Text = "";label19.Text = "";label20.Text = "";label21.Text = "";label22.Text = "";label23.Text = "";label24.Text = "";label25.Text = "";label26.Text = "";label27.Text = "";label28.Text = "";label29.Text = "";label30.Text = "";label31.Text = "";
                                   label32.Text = ""; label33.Text = ""; label34.Text = ""; label35.Text = ""; label36.Text = ""; label37.Text = ""; label38.Text = ""; label39.Text = ""; label40.Text = ""; label41.Text = ""; label42.Text = ""; label43.Text = ""; label44.Text = ""; label45.Text = ""; label46.Text = ""; label47.Text = ""; label48.Text = "";
                                    label49.Text = "";label50.Text = "";

        if (
            comboBox1.SelectedItem==null ||
            comboBox2.SelectedItem==null ||
            comboBox_semester.SelectedItem==null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Complete Detail");

        }
        else
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 50);

                labels[randomNumber].Text = String.Format("{0},\r\n{1},\r\n{2}", reader["CourseName"], reader["TeacherName"], reader["RoomName"]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want query for these two lines.

```
string a = comboBox_semester.SelectedText;
string str = "SELECT  CourseName, TeacherName, RoomName FROM Course_teacher, RoomInfo where Semester=(what should I need to write here) ORDER BY NEWID(););
```

Please Help

Comment: So you have `string a` that holds the semester chosen by the user, and you're unsure how to feed it into your query?

Comment: This does not answer your question, however I would consider it unwise to query on combobox select, since the user can make a "mistake", or just randomly click options which might slow/freeze your application/MVC

Comment: @DrewKennedy  yes this is my question

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by assigning the query results to random labels? Not fully on topic, but I'm curious.

Comment: @aaron i m trying to generate a timetable for different semesters. I want that when i select semester 1 from the combobox, it should generate timetable by selecting subjects that are taught in 1 semester and so on.. this is what i want to do... can u please help me

Comment: I used your code and i m getting an error that says "Specified Cast is Not Valid" and it is showing me error in this line                                               int a =(int)comboBox_semester.SelectedItem;

Comment: Have you tried using a gridview? You should be able to bind it to a SQLDatasource (There is a wizard in Visual Studio, also). They aren't especially pretty, but they're great for quickly displaying information from a database query.

Comment: @aaron  its working now :) thankyou so much, I need one more help.. the timetable generated now,, i want to save it in database.. how can i do that?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your variable `a` into your query like so:

```
string str = "SELECT CourseName, TeacherName, RoomName FROM Course_teacher, " + 
"RoomInfo WHERE Semester = @Semester ORDER BY NEWID()";

com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Semester", a));
```

Just note that I cleaned up your query a little bit, and I introduced [`parameterized queries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) in case you're unfamiliar with them.

Comment: It is showing me an error that says "USE OF UNASSIGNED LOCAL VARIABLE "com". Why it is coming?

Comment: @Fary It means you're not pasting the code above properly. You need to instantiate `com` first: `com = new SqlCommand(str, con);`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is going to look something like this:

```
"Where Semester = @Semester"
```

Then, on a following line, you add a Parameter to your SqlCommand object like so:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Semester", a);
```

This lets the SQLCommand object know to substitute your variable (I've named it @Semester for now) with the value you have received from the user.

Comment: Is your button's on click event set to the method you're expecting to fire?